# How can I help my videos appear higher in YouTube search results?

Tags: youtube

In other words, how can I 'search engine optimize' my YouTube videos? What does YouTube take into consideration when ranking search results? What matters most?

Comment: Have a saucy image as the thumbnail. Clickthroughs through the roof!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about search engine optimization.

Answer (score 3):

- **Name** should be descriptive and interesting (compare "Cat1!!1" and "Amazing video of a cat playing a violin blindfolded").
- Provide a good **description** to the video, especially if it is a content-heavy video like an instructional or demo video.
- Pick **appropriate tags**, the more the better but only if they are appropriate. Don't spam-tag
- Make you video a **response** to a related video to drive more traffic to it.

Answer (score 2):

In a very annoying way, you can add a long list of popular tags in the video description, and you can manage to set a sexy girl picture as the video picture preview...

So you will get more views and more haters :p

Comment: Which equals black hat SEO tactics. I find it strange that Google doesn't sanction this kind of actions.

Comment: @Alex, depending on which definition of "sanction" you use, I'd argue that google not sanctioning these actions is good. I.e., google does not sanction (approve) this, but they don't impose sanctions (punishments) for it. I agree that it's weird they don't punish it, I think it's good that they don't encourage it. ;)

Comment: I'm tempted to vote this down.. there's already enough rubbish like this on Youtube

Comment: Useless answer.

Answer (score -1):

- share your video link in add this sites so that it will get more
  visitors and high pr backlinks.
- Write more impressive description about your video.
- Add better tags to search
- Create quality video like http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeSwTTw7auY

Comment: I would consider this as product placement.

Answer (score -1):

To rank your video in You Tube search result you have to consider these 4 things :

- Choose Strong Keywords
- Include Keywords in Your Title
- Optimize the Description With Keywords
- Customize the Video Thumbnail